# Remove or unset super attribute from cart in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have been trying to remove or unset super attribute (configurable product) on cart page which have null value.

I have attached screen shot

[image]

I have two option color and premium colors if i get color option value null than it will remove from cart programatically and also remove from sales order.

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To change the display layout of listed product you have to create the following folder structure.

```
app
  |- design
     |- frontend
        |-custom-package-name
          |- custom-theme-name
             |-etc
             |-layout
             |-template
```

copy the files from **app/design/frontend/rwd(default package 1.9)** in your custom theme.

Then edit the file app/design/frontend/custom-package-name/custom-theme-name/template/catalog/product/list.phtml.

Edit the link where color label display. And add the following condition

```
if($_product->getColor()) :

your html code to display the color

else :

any other logic if you want.

endif;
```

Help of this condition we check weather color value is associated to product or not if assign then display that color name for the product otherwise keep just display label as **"Color"**.

Comment: Thanks for response. it will hide from cart but i want to hide from overall sales quote. because when i order the product than in back end color valued will null.any idea ?